# Trying to print the correct amount of '*' in place of a numeric value

Tags: c++, printing, switch-statement

Hey guys so I have a question that is probably pretty simple I just cannot think of a solution. My function void printRanges, correctly checks an arrays values for what its range is and increments the array int ticker[10]. What i want to do is print out the range and how many fall in each category with stars *, instead of the number itself.

So right now I can print it like: "00: 1" and so on, but want to know how i can print out the corresponding amount of stars in place of the number. like: "00: *" "10: **" etc. Do i have to use a bunch of for loops? or is there something really simple I am missing!

Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

// declare const variable for array size, and array prototypes
const int SIZE = 20;
void fill(int arr[SIZE]);
void print(int arr[SIZE]);
void printRanges(int arr[SIZE]);

int main() {

    // create an array with 20 components 
    int arr[SIZE] = { 0 };

    // call functions
    fill(arr);
    print(arr);
    printRanges(arr);



    // pause and exit
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

//fills array arr with 20 random numbers
void fill(int arr[SIZE]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
}

// prints the array
void print(int arr[SIZE]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
}

// finds the range of each value in the array and stores it in the array ticker, then prints
// a list from 00-90 documenting how many values are in each range
void printRanges(int arr[SIZE]) {
    int ticker[10] = { 0 };
    char star = '*';

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        switch (arr[i] / 10) {
        case 0:
            ticker[0] = ticker[0] + 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            ticker[1] = ticker[1] + 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            ticker[2] = ticker[2] + 1;
            break;
        case 3:
            ticker[3] = ticker[3] + 1;
            break;
        case 4:
            ticker[4] = ticker[4] + 1;
            break;
        case 5:
            ticker[5] = ticker[5] + 1;
            break;
        case 6:
            ticker[6] = ticker[6] + 1;
            break;
        case 7:
            ticker[7] = ticker[7] + 1;
            break;
        case 8:
            ticker[8] = ticker[8] + 1;
            break;
        case 9:
            ticker[9] = ticker[9] + 1;
            break;
        }       
    }
    cout << endl << "00: " << star;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can eliminate the switch by simplifiying. Then you want a loop to print the ranges.

```
void printRanges(int arr[SIZE]) {
    int ticker[10] = { 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        unsigned int index = arr[i] / 10;
        if (index < 10) {
            ticker[index] += 1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // Print i pre-padded with "0"
        cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << i << ": ";
        // Print the asterisks
        cout << setfill('*') << setw(ticker[i]) << "" << endl;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to

```
#include <iomanip>
```

for `setw` and `setfill`.

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/hogmiF)

Comment: Thank you a lot for the help! That really cleaned it up! I appreciate it!

Comment: Note that when I run this I get the same numbers each time because you neglect to seed the rng with [`srand()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand).

Comment: If `arr[i]` happens to be negative, oops: `ticker[-3] += 1`.

Comment: @Kaz I thought about that but `rand()` won't return an negative number. I'll fix anyway.